# Issue while obtaining a driving distance

Tags: android, google-maps

I am able to obtain a driving distance between two positions marked in Google Maps using

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + lat1 + "," + lon1 + "&destination=" + lat2 + "," + lon2 + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving
```

But when I point one of the markers to a river or sea, it still shows me a driving distance. Why is it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason for that is, the [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Introduction) calculate it's distance in setting the marked location(origin and destination). So when you place the coordinates of the marker/destination in a river or water place, it still calculates it's shortest/straight distance. Because by default Directions API worked that way.

To modified the request to return directions for another mode, or to restrict something. You can set the parameter [mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#TravelModes) and [avoid](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Restrictions). But this parameter has only specific value.

Here is example of initial request that return directions for a scenic bicycle journey that avoids major highways.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&avoid=highways&mode=bicycling&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```